# How to get a history entry to properly display on multiple lines

Tags: bash, command-history

Suppose I have entered a function at the bash prompt, on multiple lines rather than squeezing it onto one with semicolons:

```
$ function blah {
  echo blah
}
$ history -1
12690  function blah {\necho blah\n}
```

How do I get this to display with real newline characters instead of '\n'?

Comment: For a complete answer see unix.stackexchange.com/a/353407/68648

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can enable and disable this feature within Bash using the `shopt` command. From the Bash man page.

*excerpt*

```
cmdhist   If set, bash attempts to save all lines of a multiple-line
          command in the same history entry.  This allows  easy  re-editing 
          of multiline commands.

lithist   If  set,  and the cmdhist option is enabled, multi-line commands 
          are saved to the history with embedded newlines rather than using 
          semicolon separators where possible.
```

*Enables the feature*

```
$ shopt -s cmdhist
$ shopt -s lithist
```

*Disables the feature*

```
$ shopt -u cmdhist
$ shopt -u lithist
```

#### Example

```
$ shopt -s cmdhist
$ shopt -s lithist
```

Now when I run `history`:

```
   70  text=$(cat<<'EOF'
hello world\
foo\bar
EOF)
   71  text=$(cat<<'EOF'
hello world\
foo\bar
EOF
)
   72  ls
   73  cd IT/
...
...
  414  shopt -s lithist 
  415  history | less
  416  function blah {
  echo blah
}
  417  history | less
```

Comment: For a more in-depth look at multi-line history commands, both in-memory and on-disk (for new shells), see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353407/68648

Answer (score 0):

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133015/multiline-command-chunks-in-bash-history-into-multiple-lines#new-answer - make sure your history file starts with a timestamp (`#` plus Unix timestamp) or else the `history` command will still each line of a multi-line command as a separate command, even if that multi-line command was saved correctly with lithist and cmdhist.